# Opencart filter module won't work properly

Tags: opencart

Assuming  we have e-shop working on opencart and a category "Mobile Phones". Trying to set filter module up like this

```
-Touch screen
   -Yes
   -No
-Smartphone
   -Yes
   -No
```

While choosing a single option from the list it works fine , but if I want to choose smartphones list with touch screen (choosing both "yes" options), module messes all up , and shows all phones. Any ideas how to fix this ?

P.S. I know it will be better to use attributes for this options and use some attribute search extension , but in my case I need to do this way.

Thanks

Comment: I guess this is the case why the filters were implemented for. Attributes serve for a different mean. The question: do You have set the filter values in administration properly? To be honest I haven't used filters yet so cannot give any advanced help...

Comment: Thanks for answering! And yes, I think I did it properly, anyways to be sure I've watched some guides how to set up filters, so pretty sure setup was done properly.

Comment: So due to the guides/tutorials everything is set properly and the filtering still not working (just to be sure I understand the problem)...? Did You install some extensions (that should extend the default filtering in OpenCart)? **If not** this could be a general problem/bug and I'd suppose to check the OpenCart Forums whether anyone else has the same problem and eventually report an issue to OpenCart developers (if nobody did yet).

Comment: 1. Yes 
2. No
3. I have checked before coming here, hoped someone will help

Comment: This should really be sent to the module author

Answer (score 2):

This extension solves it.
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=11707

It uses 'or' logic for the attributes of each filter and 'and' logic between filters. I put it on opencart 1.5.6 and it seems to be working just fine.

**EDIT:** It appears this extension doesn't exist anymore. Also, this comment was written based on opencart 1.5.6 while the current version is 3.0.0.

Comment: This was a life saver for me. Every pro filter I tested had the same behavior, we just wanted that AND between groups of filters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, where all the products are just being listed. I believe it could be due to the fact that the filter and the shopbyprice could be conflicting. Please let us know if you find a fix

Comment: Well didn't find any solutions yet, but will post here if i do , and please let me know if u have it fixed

Answer (score 0):

This extension should work:

FixFilter OC2x - fixes default Opencart filter

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=23603

If you don't want to use extensions and know about sql queries, you can study the code of various such extension and make the necessary changes in queries in product.php model.